# LocalBroadcastManager does not work on API 30

Tags: java, android, localbroadcastmanager

I'm adapting an app to API 30 and I've found this problem.

In previous versions it works nicely with an structure like this:

On my main activity I get to declare something like this:

```
final LocalBroadcastManager mLocalBroadcastManager3;
        BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {


            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            [code]                 

            }
        };

        mLocalBroadcastManager3 = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter mIntentFilter3 = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter3.addAction("com.durga.action.exit2");
        mLocalBroadcastManager3.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, mIntentFilter3);
```

And I call it this way from a JobIntentService:

```
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                                        "com.durga.action.exit2"));
```

In API 30 this last instruction is executed but it's as if it never happened, it doesn't raise any exception, but the onReceive function declared in MainActivity is never executed.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: `LocalBroadcastManager` has been deprecated for years. "And I call it this way from a Work" -- `WorkManager` has built-in options for being notified about work progress, using `LiveData`. Beyond that, make sure that your `Worker` is running in the same process as is your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare, yes I know it's deprecated, but I use methods way more deprecated and they still work, by the way I'm not using a worker, better editing to avoid confusion.

Comment: "I use methods way more deprecated and they still work" -- but `LocalBroadcastManager` is from a library, not the framework. "Deprecated" means `LocalBroadcastManager` is not being maintained much and may be removed from the library at any point. Regardless, you have the full source code to the library, so step through the `sendBroadcast()` call in a debugger and see what is going on.

Comment: I only want to say that LocalBroadcastManager with JobIntentService works for me with API 30. And yes the receiver should be in the used activity.

Comment: @blackapps, is that in physical device? It might be an emulator bug.

Comment: In Pixel 3 XL API 30 emulator. I have no device yet.

Comment: @blackapps, I see, I'll try with a Pixel 3 XL emulator, I was using a Pixel 2 one.